# Redirect form based on radio selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So, i have a form with 3 radio buttons. Depending on which option the user selects (he can only choose one), there can be 3 situations:

- if he selects the first one, when he submits the form, he gets redirected to a new URL.
- if he selects the second one, a div appears (and then disappears).
- if he selects the third one, a div appears (different from the previous one), and then it also disappears.

My HTML:

```
<form>
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="paypal" value="paypal"</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="money" value="money"></label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="mastercard" value="mastercard"></label>
      </div>
</form>
<button type="button" id="button1" name="button">Check</button>
```

My JQuery:

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value == 'paypal') {
    window.location.assign("http://www.paypal.com");
}
  else if (value == 'money') {
    $('.div2').show('slow'); 
      $('.div2').fadeOut(4000);
}
}
  else if (value == 'mastercard') {
    $('.div1').show('slow'); 
       $('.div1').fadeOut(4000);
}
```

But something is not working in here, and I can't figure out what or where.
EDIT: No error, the JQuery code just doesn't work. Whatever option I choose, when I submit nothing happens.

Comment: error ? exception on console ? or any others, please specify the problem .

Comment: "he can only choose one" : Your radio buttons name should be same.

Answer (score 1):

By using `var value = $(this).val();` inside the button click, you are actually taking the value of the button itself which is not you are intending to do.

Make all `radio` button name same. Try the following code:

```js
$('#button1').click(function() {
  var value = $('input[name=myRadio]:checked').val();
  if (value == 'paypal') {
    console.log(value);
    window.location.assign("http://www.paypal.com");
  }
  else if (value == 'money') {
    console.log(value);
    $('.div2').show('slow'); 
    $('.div2').fadeOut(4000);
  }

  else if (value == 'mastercard') {
    console.log(value);
    $('.div1').show('slow'); 
    $('.div1').fadeOut(4000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="paypal">Pay Pal</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="money">Money</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="mastercard">Master Card</label>
  </div>
</form>
<button type="button" id="button1" name="button">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `submit` button along with the submit form event like below to make it work exactly as you like, and group the radio buttons by assigning similar names, and try to reduce the if else and make it more readable like the code below

```js
let formEvents = {
  paypal: function() {
    console.log('redirecting');
    //uncomment the following line when you use it in your script
    //window.location.assign("http://www.paypal.com");
  },
  money: function() {
    $('.div2').show('slow', function() {
      setTimeout("$('.div2').fadeOut(4000)", 500);
    });
  },
  mastercard: function() {
    $('.div1').show('slow', function() {
      $('.div1').fadeOut(4000);
    });
  }
}

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = $(this).find('input:radio:checked').val();

  if (formEvents.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
    formEvents[value].call(this);
  }

});
```

```css
.div1,
.div2 {
  display: none;
  background: #c8c8c8;
  border: 2px dashed #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="selection" value="paypal">paypal</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="selection" value="money">money</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="selection" value="mastercard">mastercard</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="button1" name="button">Check</button>
</form>


<div class="div1">div 1</div>
<div class="div2">div 2</div>
```